# How can I automate a python script in interactive mode that takes arguments

Tags: python, interactive

I have a script that I can call as:
import os

```
os.system("python -i myscript.py --port=2")
```

The above works and gets me to the interactive shell mode but there are additional commands that I want to run once in the Interactive Shell. 
How can I automate this process?
Let's say once in the interactive shell the next command is `a.getname()`. Any ideas?

Comment: Try looking into using `subprocess` and `subprocess.communicate()` instead of `os.system()`. Python2: https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html Python3: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html.

Comment: yes, I have tried pexcept as well but no luck